# Spring Boot 3 Postgres TestContainers SQL Exception

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, testcontainers, spring-boot-testcontainers

I am using Spring Boot 3.1.3 and Java 17

test application.yml

```
spring:
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:tc:postgresql:///test_tc_db?TC_IMAGE_TAG=13.3
```

my test

```
@SpringBootTest
class KotlinApplicationTests {

    @Test
    fun contextLoads() {
        
    }
}
```

schema.sql

```
create table if not exists customer
(
    id serial primary key,
    name text not null
);
```

my gradle

```
extra["testcontainersVersion"] = "1.18.3"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:r2dbc")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:${property("testcontainersVersion")}")
    }
}
```

Error:

io.r2dbc.postgresql.ExceptionFactory$PostgresqlBadGrammarException: [42601] syntax error at end of input

Comment: Have you tried to check if the script from `schema.sql` is a valid one yet ?  because usually this kind of exception is throwing when something not meet the database language specification.